# Could the Amazon's jungle exist in a continent without the Andes mountain chain?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, climate

I assume a planet like earth. Obviously the Amazon river is fed into the Andes mountains as well as other rivers that give water to the system. Could the same amount of water come from a specific climate setting? Would a lighter terrain slope be enough to distribute that water and create such an environment? Would ocean currents change the climate making it less homogeneous?

Answer (score 4):

The Amazon rainforest is the result of the moisture-laden equitorial region. If you look at a [Koppen-Geiger climate map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6ppen_climate_classification), you'll note the Amazon, African, Southeast Asian and Oceanian tropical forests all occupy the same latitudes. A mountain range like the Andes simply isn't necessary factor.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly.  The mountains in [Borneo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borneo#/media/File%3ABorneo_Locator_Topography.png) never reach above a couple thousand meters, and yet you can see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainforest#/media/File%3AKoppen-Geiger_Map_Af_present.svg) that it is entirely covered in rainforest.

Comment: Even better: Florida never reaches more than about 100 m above sea level, but large parts of it are (or were before modern populations arrived)  impenetrable jungle.  There's also the Congo basin in Africa...

Comment: @jamesqf - Because he is talking about mountains and water systems I think he means the river, not the rainforest.